# How to install Traefik v2 ingress daemonset with helm?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

Is it possible to use the Traefik v2 helm chart from their own repository - not the stable repo - to install the DaemonSet instead of a Deployment?

I don't see any instructions or examples of how to use the helm chart to install Traefik as a DaemonSet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to [this Helm chart](https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart/tree/master/traefik). Yes, but I'm afraid that you will have to modify the chart on your own . You can clone the repo and host your own [Helm repository on Github](https://blog.softwaremill.com/hosting-helm-private-repository-from-github-ff3fa940d0b7) .

I believe changing ↩ the [resource Kind](https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/templates/deployment.yaml#L14) from `Deployment` to `DaemonSet` and also removing the [replicas spec](https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/templates/deployment.yaml#L27-L29) should do.

✌️☮️

Comment: thx for your reply, didnt work. I am using a values.yaml file to make my edits. there is nowhere to specify the resource kind. it has "deployment : enabled: true instead.

Comment: Well, you need to modify the template. Also, make sure chart is not using that `deployment : enabled: true` value anywhere.

Comment: I did modify the template. perhaps I am doing it wrong. can be be specific on exactly what I have to modify? I think you are not referring to modifying a values.yaml file?

Comment: I was referring to just changing this: https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/templates/deployment.yaml#L14. But how would that not work has me puzzled. Are you sure you are deploying from the modified helm template?

Comment: That link only refers to using a deployment. Can you provide an actual example that shows a daemonset ?